# Place div side by side to fill container without fixing width?

Tags: html, css

I have this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qa5dr0x8/130/

I dynamically create divs, so i dont know how many will i have them and i dont know width of them. I manage to achive to have them in one line but there is a space after last div in container. What i want to to fill container with that divs even if i dont know width any of them. I would love to achive that without using flex. Any suggestion ?

```
<body>
  <div style="widht:30%">
    test text
  </div>
  <div style="width:70%;border:1px solid black;">
    <div style="background-color:red;display:inline-block;">
    a1fsdfsdfsd
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow;display:inline-block;">
    b1dfsd
    </div>f
    <div style="background-color:blue;display:inline-block;">
    c1d
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `display: table` instead of `flex` for the wrapper and use `display:table-cell` for the variable divs.

```
  <div style="widht:30%">
    test text
  </div>
  <div style="width:70%;border:1px solid black; display: table">
    <div style="background-color:red;display:table-cell;">
    a1fsdfsdfsd
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow;display:table-cell;">
    b1dfsd
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:blue;display:table-cell;">
    c1d
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qa5dr0x8/131/

Answer (score -2):

```
  <body>
  <div style="width:30%">
    test text
  </div>
  <div style="width:70%;border:1px solid black;display:inline;">
    <div style="background-color:red;display:inline-block;">
    a1fsdfsdfsd
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:yellow;display:inline-block;">
    b1dfsd
    </div>f
    <div style="background-color:blue;display:inline-block;">
    c1d
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you want all in same line without space and without using flex then you can add css display:inline; in this div

```
<div style="width:70%;border:1px solid black;display:inline;">
```

Comment: i dont want to "cut" rest of parent div